# Windows: Create folder structure based on XML file

Tags: xml, powershell, batch-file, directory

I'm trying to find a way to create a full folder/subfolders/files(shortcuts) arborescence in Windows, based on an XML file input.

My XML looks like this:

```
<folder name="Folder1">
    <shortcut url="http://A.com" name="A" />
    <shortcut url="http://B.com" name="B" />
    <folder name="1.1">
        <shortcut url="http://C.com" name="C" />
    </folder>
    <folder name="Folder1.2">
        <shortcut url="http://D.com" name="D" />
    </folder>
</folder>
<folder name="Folder2">
    ...
</folder>
```

And the resulting folders would be:

- Folder1

  - A.url
  - B.url
  - Folder1.1

    - C.url
  - Folder1.2

    - D.url
- Folder2

  - ...

-> To sum up, recursive folders/subfolders creation, plus creation of shortcuts (.url files)

Any idea on how to do this? 
Via cmd, powershell ?

(if .url files creation in not possible, i'll make them manually (more than 300...) )

Many thanks!

---

EDIT: SOLUTION

Thanks @rojo, good direction.
I've modified my need of creation "Shortcuts" by html files. (content truncated here, just for sample)
I've added a target path, several errors handling (folders and files creation, by creating error txt files, easily searchable to fix manually), as well as added the creation of files at root. (not in subfolders)

Probably not very optimized, but well...

```
<# : Batch Portion
@echo off & setlocal

powershell -noprofile -noexit -noninteractive "iex (gc \"%~f0\" | out-string)"
goto :EOF

: End Batch / begin PowerShell hybrid chimera #>

[xml]$DOM = gc clv.xml
$destPath="D:\Test\Folders"

function CreateShortcut([string]$target, [string]$saveLoc, [string]$fileName) {

$aspxText= @"
<html>
<body>
<a href="$target">Target URL</a>
</form>
</body>
</html>
"@  
try{
New-Item ($saveLoc+'/'+$fileName+'.aspx') -type file -value  $aspxText -ea Stop
}
catch{
$err=@"
Name:
$fileName
Url:
$target

Error:
$_.Exception.GetType().FUllname
"@

New-Item ($saveLoc+'/###Error.txt') -type file -value  $txtDoc
}

    write-host "$($saveLoc)\$($fileName)" -f cyan
}

cd $destPath
function launchCreation($root){
    $rootshortcuts = @($root.shortcut)
    if($rootshortcuts -ne $null){
        foreach ($shortcut in $rootshortcuts) {
            $fixedShortcutName=$shortcut.name  -replace '[<>:"\/\\?\*\|]', '-'
            $urlfile = (pwd).Path
            CreateShortcut $shortcut.url $urlfile $fixedShortcutName $shortcut.isDoc $shortcut.isTaxo
        }
    }
    Walk($root)
}
function Walk($root) {  
    $folders = @($root.folder)
    if($folders -ne $null){
        foreach ($folder in $folders) {
            $folderName=$folder.name -replace '[<>:"\/\\?\*\|]', '-'
            if (-not (test-path $folderName)) {  md $folderName }
            cd $folderName
            write-host (Join-Path $destPath $folderName) -f magenta
            $shortcuts = @($folder.shortcut)
            if($shortcuts -ne $null){
                foreach ($shortcut in $shortcuts) {
                    $fixedShortcutName=$shortcut.name  -replace '[<>:"\/\\?\*\|]', '-'
                    $urlfile = (pwd).Path
                    CreateShortcut $shortcut.url $urlfile $fixedShortcutName $shortcut.isDoc $shortcut.isTaxo
                }
            }
            Walk $folder
            cd..
        }
    }

}

[void](launchCreation $DOM.documentElement)
```

Comment: use powershell (PowerGUI for example) with .net classes if you know c# or use excel vba (just as vb6 IDE for running and debugging) if wou now vb6

Comment: This is easy enough with a script. I would use powershell, but that's more of a personal preference. Use what you know or what you want to learn. I would recommend searching for "powershell xml" and the cmdlet "new-item". If you get into a problem ask it here and we'll help, but at this point the question is too wide. More of a request/order than a QA-question.

Comment: Edited my question with code based on rojo's helpful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Challenge accepted, but only to discourage others' attempts to parse XML as flat text to be tokenized and scraped.  In the future, please make an effort to write your own code, and post what you have written when asking for help.

I whipped up a quick and dirty PowerShell script that does what you want.  It imports the XML as an XML object, then recursively walks the DOM, creating directories where they don't exist and creating shortcuts.  The XML **must** be well-formed and valid for this to work.

Here's the XML I used to test the script:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <folder name="Folder1">
        <shortcut url="http://A.com" name="A" />
        <shortcut url="http://B.com" name="B" />
        <folder name="1.1">
            <shortcut url="http://C.com" name="C" />
        </folder>
        <folder name="Folder1.2">
            <shortcut url="http://D.com" name="D" />
        </folder>
    </folder>
    <folder name="Folder2">
        <shortcut url="http://E.com" name="E" />
    </folder>
</root>
```

And here's the .PS1 script:

```js
[xml]$DOM = gc folders.xml
$shell = New-Object -COM WScript.Shell

function CreateShortcut([string]$target, [string]$saveLoc) {
    $shortcut = $shell.CreateShortcut($saveLoc + ".url")
    $shortcut.TargetPath = $target
    $shortcut.Save()
    write-host $shortcut.FullName -f cyan
}

function Walk($root) {
    foreach ($folder in $root.folder) {
        if (-not (test-path $folder.name)) { md $folder.name }
        cd $folder.name
        write-host (pwd).Path -f magenta
        foreach ($shortcut in $folder.shortcut) {
            $urlfile = ((pwd).Path, $shortcut.name) -join '\'
            CreateShortcut $shortcut.url $urlfile
        }
        Walk $folder
        cd ..
    }
}

[void](Walk $DOM.documentElement)
```

If you'd rather have a .bat script, just insert this comment block into the top of the script and give the thing a .bat extension:

```js
<# : Batch Portion
@echo off & setlocal

powershell -noprofile -noninteractive "iex (gc \"%~f0\" | out-string)"
goto :EOF

: End Batch / begin PowerShell hybrid chimera #>
```

Comment: Many thanks !! Nice to have a real XMl parser instead of relying on line breaks! it points me to the right direction, but i broke it all... Please see my edited question with code

Comment: loops indefinitely... Looks like it loops on non existing nodes...

Answer (score 0):

This type of problems are easily solved via a recursive process. The solution below just *show* the `md` & `cd` commands required to create the folder structure; if the result looks correct, remove the `ECHO` part from each command. I hope this method is simple enough so it don't require explanations.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

call :treeProcess < input.xml
goto :EOF


:treeProcess
   set "line=:EOF"
   set /P "line="
   for /F "tokens=1-5 delims=<=> " %%a in ("%line%") do (
      if "%%a" equ "folder" (
         ECHO md "%%~c"
         ECHO cd "%%~c"
         call :treeProcess
      ) else if "%%a" equ "shortcut" (
         echo Create here "%%~e.url"
      ) else if "%%a" equ "/folder" (
         ECHO cd ..
         exit /B
      )
   )
if "%line%" neq ":EOF" goto treeProcess
exit /B
```

This is the output with the input provided:

```
md "Folder1"
cd "Folder1"
Create here "A.url"
Create here "B.url"
md "1.1"
cd "1.1"
Create here "C.url"
cd ..
md "Folder1.2"
cd "Folder1.2"
Create here "D.url"
cd ..
cd ..
md "Folder2"
cd "Folder2"
cd ..
```

Answer (score -1):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q3489447.txt"
PUSHD "%destdir%"
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=*" %%z IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1-6delims=<=>" %%a IN ('echo "%%z"') DO (
  IF "%%~b"=="shortcut url" CALL :mdshortcut %%d
  IF "%%~b"=="folder name" MD "%%c"&CD "%%c"
  IF "%%~b"=="/folder" CD ..
 )
)
POPD

GOTO :EOF

:mdshortcut
MD "%~1.url"
GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q3489447.txt` containing your data for my testing.

- go to the destination directory
- Read the file; strip leading spaces to `%%z`
- using appropriate delimiters, break the line into parts
- if the second part is `folder name` then create a new directory and change to it
- if the second part is `/folder` come back up one directory level.
- if the second part is `shortcut url` then call a subroutine passing the fourth part, the first element of which is the desired new directory name to which `.url` is appended.
- go back to original directory when finished

You could append `2>nul` to the `md` commands to suppress complaints that a directory already exists.

Comment: No good deed goes unpunished, huh?